# Объдинение разных результатов в одну строку, но в разные столбцы в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Всем привет. Есть таблица: table со столбцами id и option_id. id - это идентификатор компании, а option_id - это подключенные услуги, возможные значения: 1,2,3,4,5.
У id может быть несколько значений из option_id, выглядит примерно так:

| id | option_id |
| --- | --- |
| 7777 | 1 |
| 7777 | 3 |
| 7777 | 4 |

Нужно вывести формат: id, Есть услуга 2, Есть услуга 4.
И в значениях строк вместо 2 и 4 указывать Да или Нет.

Ожидаемый результат:

| id | Есть услуга 2 | Есть услуга 4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7777 | Да | Нет |
| 7978 | Да | Да |
| 8392 | Нет | Да |

Я использую такой запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
 CASE WHEN option_id IN (1,3,4,5) THEN 'Нет' WHEN option_id = 2 THEN 'Да'ELSE CAST(option_id AS CHAR(20))  
 END "Есть услуга 2", 
  CASE WHEN option_id IN (1,2,3,5) THEN 'Нет' WHEN option_id = 4 THEN 'Да'ELSE CAST(option_id AS CHAR(20))  
 END "Есть услуга 4"
FROM table
```

Но получаю результат:

| id | Есть услуга 2 | Есть услуга 4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7777 | Нет | Нет |
| 7777 | Да | Нет |
| 7777 | Нет | Да |
| 7778 | Нет | Нет |
| 7778 | Да | Нет |

Т.е. мой запрос выводит дополнительные строки для id по каждому значению, а хотелось бы чтоб id не повторялся и приоритетно выводились только значения 2,4 = Да, а все остальное Нет и не создавались дополнительные строки. Как можно пофиксить?

Comment: в общем случае для такого надо в сторону группировки смотреть, Но можно и джойнить. и даже на подзапросах тоже можно

Comment: Обычная условная агрегация. ```SELECT .. CASE WHEN SUM(option_id=3) THEN 'Да' ELSE 'Нет' END AS `Есть услуга 3`, ..```

Comment: @Akina Спасибо, попробовал, но возвращает только один id в таком случае. Убираю sum, и возвращаюсь к прежнему результату.

Comment: GROUP BY не пробовал добавить?

Comment: @Akina Да! Все получилось, спасибо. Постараюсь теперь понять как это работает.